# Upload to ADLS from file stream

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am making a custom activity in ADF, which involves reading multiple files from Azure Storage Blobs, doing some work on them, and then finally writing a resulting file to the Azure Data Lake Store. 
Last step is where I stop, because as far as I can see, the .NET SDK only allows for uploading from a local file.

Is there any way to to (programmatically) upload a file to ADL Store, where it is *not* from a local file? Could be a blob or a stream. If not, any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to upload from Stream, the trick is to create file first and then append your stream to it:

```
string dataLakeAccount = "DLSAccountName";
var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(credentials);
adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create(dataLakeAccount, filepath, overwrite: true);
adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Append(dataLakeAccount, filepath, stream);
```

See also [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! On a side note, I had already seen the article referred, and strangely it doesn't mention the .Create method.