# Azure Data Lake : Facing issue while moving data from Blob to ADLS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

I am creating an Azure Function in C# which does following things:

- extracts the zipped file from a blob,
- unzips it and copies it to Azure Data Lake Store.

I was able to unzip the file and upload it into another blob using the UploadFromStreamAsync(stream) function.

However, I am facing issue while doing the same For ADLS

I referred to the below link [Upload to ADLS from file stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645199/upload-to-adls-from-file-stream) and tried to first create the file using `adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create` and then append the stream using  `adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Append` in data lake but it did not work. 
 - The create method creates a **zero byte** file but the append does nothing and the azure function still completes successfully without any error. Also, tried with `adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.AppendAsync` and still the same problem.

**Code:**

```
 // Save blob(zip file) contents to a Memory Stream.
    using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipBlobFileStream);
        await zipBlobFileStream.FlushAsync(); 
        zipBlobFileStream.Position = 0;

        //use ZipArchive from System.IO.Compression to extract all the files from zip file
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipBlobFileStream))
        {
        //Each entry here represents an individual file or a folder
        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            string destfilename = $"{destcontanierPath2}/"+entry.FullName;
            log.Info($"DestFilename: {destfilename}");
            //creating an empty file (blobkBlob) for the actual file with the same name of file
            var blob = extractcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{destfilename}");
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                //check for file or folder and update the above blob reference with actual content from stream
                if (entry.Length > 0)
                {
                    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

                    //Creating a file and then append
                    adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create(_adlsAccountName, "/raw/Hello.txt",overwrite:true); 
                    // Appending the stream to Azure Data Lake 
                    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(ms);
                        ms.Position = 0; // rewind
                        log.Info($"**********MemoryStream: {ms}");
                        // do something with ms
                        await adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.AppendAsync(_adlsAccountName, "/raw/Hello.txt",ms,0);
                    }
                }
            }                           
        }
        }
    }
```

New Interim Solution:

```
    using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipBlobFileStream);
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipBlobFileStream))
        {
            //Each entry here represents an individual file or a folder
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
            {   
                    entry.ExtractToFile(directoryPath + entry.FullName, true);
                    //Upload the File to ADLS
                    var parameters = new UploadParameters(directoryPath + entry.FullName, "/raw/" + md5, _adlsAccountName, isOverwrite: true, maxSegmentLength: 268435456 * 2);
                    var frontend = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader.DataLakeStoreFrontEndAdapter(_adlsAccountName, adlsFileSystemClient);
                    var uploader = new DataLakeStoreUploader(parameters, frontend);
                    uploader.Execute();
                    File.Delete(directoryPath + entry.FullName);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post your code ?

Comment: @Thomas : I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, You could change your code as following, then it should work. You should remove the create file code out of the foreach clause.

```
//Creating a file and then append
adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Create(_adlsAccountName, "/raw/Hello.txt",overwrite:true); 

 using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipBlobFileStream);
        await zipBlobFileStream.FlushAsync(); 
        zipBlobFileStream.Position = 0;

        //use ZipArchive from System.IO.Compression to extract all the files from zip file
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipBlobFileStream))
        {
        //Each entry here represents an individual file or a folder
        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            string destfilename = $"{destcontanierPath2}/"+entry.FullName;
            log.Info($"DestFilename: {destfilename}");
            //creating an empty file (blobkBlob) for the actual file with the same name of file
            var blob = extractcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{destfilename}");
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                //check for file or folder and update the above blob reference with actual content from stream
                if (entry.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                                ms.Position = 0;
                                blob.UploadFromStream(ms);
                                ms.Position = 0;                                   
                      adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Append(adlsAccountName, "/raw/Hello.txt", ms);

                            }
                  }
                }
            }                           
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the above solution. I had tried the above code and it fails due to Out of Memory Exception. The uncompressed file is between 180-250 MB

Comment: I also update the code in the answer. If your compressed file is out  of Memory. I suggest you using FileStream. You need to save it as temp file. And then read it as Filetream .

Comment: As an interim solution I did the same thing. Not the most efficient way as there is an additional hop. Updated my question with the new code